# Including codeigniter from a normal PHP file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

A 3rd party service that I'm using returns the users to a url like this:

```
site.com/something.php?id=XXX&something=abc....
```

Therefore, I need to be able to accept `$_GET` parameters for only one part of the site.

Is there a way to put a file outside of codeigniter's application directory which will do something like this:

```
<?
$id = $_GET['id'];
$something = $_GET['something'];

//Do something so codeigniter thinks this is a request to site.com/process/$id/$something

require('index.php'); //codeigniter's index.php file
?>
```

I remember using `putenv()` to achieve this in the past, but don't remember the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about putenv, but if worse comes to worse you can get the contents of the get array by exploding `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

get doesn't need to be enabled and you still have access.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using a redirect:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$something = $_GET['something'];
header('Location: http://www.site.com/' . $id . '/' . $something);
```

As long as the initial `something.php` request is made directly to that file and not `index.php`, then CodeIgniter won't run (actually, that would depend on your .htaccess [or equivalent] file, so you may need to tweak it).

That's the safest way I can think to do it, and you won't have to break up CodeIgniter's program flow or enable query strings in your application, which may be unsafe.

Comment: Can't do that, I need reliable access to the HTTP referrer and other stuff. I need to include the index.php file directly

Comment: In that case you may be able to do `require('index.php')` and use the GET array as mentioned above, but I don't think you'll be able to pass those values as the controller name and parameters the way your question says you'd like to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done that in the past, I used `putenv()` to put in `controller/method` somewhere to make index.php think that it was a direct url access to that controller, but I can't remember what setting I had used in `putenv`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your architecture but couldn't you just enable GET for codeigniter..?

See `$config['allow_get_array']` in the docs:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

And see `$this->input->get()` on the same page..

Comment: I need to enable it only for one function and keep it disabled for the rest

Comment: Why does it matter if it's enabled throughout?

Comment: enabling the GET array in codeigniter is a really really bad idea.  It will break alot of other things.

Comment: yes.  let me amend my statement.  while its not always a bad idea, it can be depending on what your uri_protocol is set to in config. I've had issues in the past, but it was a while ago, so i'll assume i was using something quirky in my config.  but that being said, parsing the variable from the server is probably a better solution than changing config items for one request. I think facebooks opengraph uses a return url like this and when I have an opportunity to see how I handled that I can elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->config->set_item("allow_get_array",TRUE);
```

in your controller's constructor before `parent::__construct();`.

> The security filtering function is called automatically when a new
>   controller is invoked. It does the following:
>
> If $config['allow_get_array'] is FALSE(default is TRUE), destroys the
>   global GET array.

Comment: Won't work, need to do the parent::constructor before `$this->config` will work